# Excel VBA: Search for tables under specific style heading of an MS Word file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I need to make the following Excel VBA code work in order to look for all the tables under **style heading level 2 "BAS"** where each table within the heading "**BAS**" must:

1. have `11` rows,
2. have a background color of `15189684` for the first row,
3. and it must contain the regex pattern `[OBASRMCHUIVELNG]{3}[1-4][1-9]{2}`.

```
Sub findTables()
    Dim wdApp As Object
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim wdRange As Object
    Dim wdTable As Object
    
    Set wdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    wdApp.Visible = True
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents("Test.docx")
    
    For Each wdRange In wdDoc.StoryRanges
        With wdRange.Find
            .Style = wdStyleHeading2 ' check if the style exists
            .Text = "BAS"
            If .Execute() Then
                For Each wdTable In wdRange.Tables

                    ' check if the table meets the criteria
                    If wdTable.Rows.Count = 11 And wdTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = 15189684 And _
                        RegExpTest("[OBASRMCHUIVELNG]{3}[1-4][1-9]{2}", wdTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text) Then
                        
                        ' do something with the table
                        MsgBox "Table found"
                        
                    End If
                Next wdTable
            End If
        End With
    Next wdRange
    
    'wdDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub

Function RegExpTest(str As String, strPattern As String) As Boolean
    Dim objRegExp As Object
    Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegExp.Pattern = str
    RegExpTest = objRegExp.Test(strPattern)
End Function
```

Comment: What goes wrong? Is RegExpTest ever called? If so, does it ever succeed?

Comment: @jonsson I get an error at this line `.Style = wdStyleHeading2` `Run-time error '4608' Value out of range`.

Comment: You are running your code in Excel. Excel doesn't understand Word's enums. Write `-3` instead of `wdStyleHeading2`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is a result of your use of late binding.

When using late binding you cannot use the enums or constants from the Word object library as Excel doesn't know what those represent. If you must use late binding, you must either declare those constants yourself or use their underlying values.

Your best option is to set a reference to the Word library under Tools | References as there is little value to using late binding in this instance. The only advantage to late binding is version independence, i.e. you can write code in a newer version, and it will theoretically work in an older one. But that advantage is lost unless you also use late binding for the host application code as Office is usually installed as a package. It is better to use early binding when working with other Office applications and reserve late binding for other commonly used libraries, such as RegEx.